# Why do i have a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC" in PHP?

Tags: php

i'm doing the Property Panic (2) from Using Objects in PHP course (Codeacademy.com), but I have this error.
Here's my code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
  <title>Reconstructing the Person Class</title>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
  <?php

    class Person{
        public $isAlive = true;
        public $firstname;
        public $lastname;
        public $age;
    }



   public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age){
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    $teacher = new Person("boring","12345",12345);
    $student = new Person("a","b",23);

    echo $teacher->age;
    ?>

  </p>
</body>
```

Where does it come from? Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, well thank you again. I'll do this now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your constructor belongs *inside* your class:

```
class Person{
    public $isAlive = true;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age){
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->age = $age;
    } 
}
```